# Time stamp won't show in my contacts database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, timestamp

I am doing an online course , and I am trying to design a website with a user database . I have built a " Contact Us" page with a form/table . 
I cannot make the timestamps show in the rails console  $ Contact.all

this is my Schema.rb :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20190518115940) do

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.text   "comments"
  end
end
```

And this is the crate_contacts.rb file :

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `schema.rb` knows nothing about timestamps. Did you created the table without `timestamps` and then you added it to the migration?

If so, you can rerun the migration (assuming it is the last one) with the command `rails db:migrate:redo`, but all the data in that table will be wiped.

Refer to [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back) for further options.

Comment: Thank you ! I have updated my schema.rb with : ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20190518115940) do

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end

Comment: And then I reran the migration as you suggested and now it works . Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome. Please, consider to mark this answer as correct to help other users. Thanks.